# cocoa NSArrayController show custom wizard on add action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have the `NSArrayController` and `NSTableView`, also linked "add" button with add method of `NSArrayController`. When I clicked the add button - it just create new row at `NSTableView`.
I wish to show my custom wizard, where user can input all necessary information. 
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to do some custom action you need to do it programatically.

Create an `outlet` for the `NSArrayController`.

Create an `IBAction` for the Add button. Show your wizard here.

Then call the add method for `NSArrayController`.